# Recursive function in node.js using q library

Tags: javascript, node.js, recursion, promise, q

I need to prepare JSON by fetching the data from MYSQL. I have data in MYSQl in tree structure. I am trying to make recursive function to prepare JSON to meet the requirement but getting errors, I have following two files

main.js

```
/* jshint node: true */
"use strict";

var db = require('./helpers/db');
var list_worker = require('./workers/list');
var Q = require("q");

module.exports = function (app) {
/**
 * return the profiles list
 */
app.get('/api/lists/get_list_tree_by_user/:user_id', function (req, res) {

    list_worker.fetch_list_tree(req.params.user_id, 0).done(function (out) {
        console.log(out);
        res.send(out);
    });
});
};
```

list.js

```
/* jshint node: true */
"use strict";

var db = require('../helpers/db');
var Q = require("q");
var output = {
    data: []
};

var fetch_list_tree = function (user_id, list_id) {

// prepare query to fetch lists assosiated with a user.
var query = "SELECT b.`id`, b.`name` FROM `lists_users` a JOIN `lists` b ON(a.`list_id` = b.`id`) WHERE a.`user_id` = " + user_id + " AND a.`user_role` = 'owner' AND b.`parent_id` = " + list_id + " AND b.`deleted` = 'N';";

return db.query(query).then(function (result) {

    if (result.length > 0) {
        var lists = result.map(function (list, index) {

            output.data[index] = {
                label: list.name,
                data: {
                    id: list.id
                }
            };

            return fetch_list_tree(user_id, list.id).then(function (leaf_childs) {
                output.data[index].children = [];
                output.data[index].children.push(leaf_childs);
                return leaf_childs;
            });
        });

        return Q.all(lists).then(function (data) {
            return output;
        }, function (err) {
            throw err;
        });
    } else {
        return [];
    }
}, function (err) {
    throw err;
});
};

module.exports = {
    fetch_list_tree: fetch_list_tree
};
```

data in database I am having is
    item 1
        item 1.1
            item 1.1.1
    item 2

Output I want
        `{
            "label": "item 1",
            "data": {
                "id": "1"
            },
            "children": [{
                "label": "item 1.1",
                "data": {
                    "id": "2"
                },
                "children": [{
                    "label": "item 1.1.1",
                    "data": {
                        "id": "3"
                    },
                    "children": []
                }]
            }]
        }`

I am getting the following error

`TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON`

Answer (score 0):

Try change `this.fetch_list_tree` to `exports.fetch_list_tree`.

`this != module.exports` on line 28 => undefined

Comment: I am getting the error after updating this.fetch_list_tree to exports.fetch_list_tree   TypeError: exports.fetch_list_tree is not a function

Comment: I did some R&D and got the problem, I was not able to call the function, I have made some changes in list.js but not getting desired out, I updated the current error too. I am not able to handle `output` as it should be.

Comment: `Converting circular structure to JSON` means that some node of result reference by itself. Try `JSON.stringify(result, ['label', 'data', 'children'])`.